# Can't install ios application through JENKINS

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xctool

my Jenkins build failed with the following output. What it can be?

```
14:27:19   [Info] Collecting info for testables... (2378 ms)
14:27:20   run-test HorizonTests.xctest (iphonesimulator7.1, application-test)
14:27:20     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.upc.h.UPCTV.development' but failed. (33 ms)
14:27:20     [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 2 more times (0 ms)
14:27:21     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.upc.h.UPCTV.development' but failed. (31 ms)
14:27:21     [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 1 more time (0 ms)
14:27:22     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.upc.horizon.UPCTV.development' but failed. (30 ms)
14:27:22     [Info] Preparing test environment failed. (0 ms)
14:27:32       -[TEST_BUNDLE FAILED_TO_START]
```